# Hibernate's PhysicalNamingStrategy's toPhysicalSchemaName does not get called

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate and trying to externalize the entity's table and column names to a .properties file. I've implemented the `PhysicalNamingStrategy` to map the entity properties and when executed everything works correctly (i.e., the methods `toPhysicalTableName` and `toPhysicalColumnName` get called for the table name and every mapped property, respectively). 
However the `toPhysicalSchemaName` doesn't get called, even if I provide the annotation `@Table(schema="SCHEMA_NAME")`. The documentation says that

> The `PhysicalNamingStrategy` will be applied regardless of whether the attribute explicitly specified the column name or whether we determined that implicitly. The `ImplicitNamingStrategy` would only be applied if an explicit name was not given.

I do not know if this applies to the schema name too. The `toPhysicalSchemaName` just won't get called no matter what I do. Should I be configuring the schema name differently for this to work?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging found out that the hibernate-core 5.2.2.Final incorrectly creates the namespace. The `org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Namespace.java` constructor has the following line

```
this.physicalName = new Namespace.Name(
    database.getPhysicalNamingStrategy()
            .toPhysicalCatalogName(name.getCatalog(), database.getJdbcEnvironment()), 
    database.getPhysicalNamingStrategy()
            .toPhysicalCatalogName(name.getSchema(), database.getJdbcEnvironment())
);
```

The Name constructor expects the second argument to be the schema name, but the catalog gets passed again. Instead it should have been

```
this.physicalName = new Namespace.Name(
    database.getPhysicalNamingStrategy()
            .toPhysicalCatalogName(name.getCatalog(), database.getJdbcEnvironment()), 
    database.getPhysicalNamingStrategy()
            .toPhysicalSchemaName(name.getSchema(), database.getJdbcEnvironment())
);
```

**This is fixed in hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.**